# Не грузится шрифт в Python Pillow

Tags: python, шрифты, pil, pillow

Код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor, ImageDraw, ImageFont

spam1=Image.new("RGB", (1500, 1000), "#000096")
spam2=ImageFont.load("arial.pil")
spam3=ImageDraw.Draw(spam1)
spam3.text((1450, 950), "IAmGM", font=spam2)
spam1.save("hello.png")
```

Результат:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Gosha/experiment.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Gosha/experiment.py", line 4, in <module>
    spam2=ImageFont.load("arial.pil")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 229, in load
    f._load_pilfont(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 69, in _load_pilfont
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arial.pil'
```

И что делать?

Comment: Указать правильный путь к файлу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас отсутствует файл с растровым шрифтом "arial.pil" или расположен в другой директории (в этом случае укажите полный путь к файлу).

PIL начиная с версии 1.1.4 поддерживает шрифты TrueType и OpenType типов. Под Windows если указанный файл шрифта найти не удалось, `ImageFont.truetype()` ищет указанный файл также в директории `%SystemRoot%/fonts` (например: `C:\Windows\fonts`) :

```
spam2=ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf")
```

из Docstring:

```
In [7]: ImageFont.truetype?
Signature: ImageFont.truetype(font=None, size=10, index=0, encoding='', layout_engine=None)
Docstring:
Load a TrueType or OpenType font from a file or file-like object,
and create a font object.
This function loads a font object from the given file or file-like
object, and creates a font object for a font of the given size.

This function requires the _imagingft service.

:param font: A filename or file-like object containing a TrueType font.
                 Under Windows, if the file is not found in this filename,
                 the loader also looks in Windows :file:`fonts/` directory.
...
```